# Load Javascript SDK outside Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am working on a use case suggesting some Facebook user may invite his friends to use a given Facebook app, regardless of whether this user is using the App or not. This implies invoking dialogs from the Facebook JS SDK outside of the App Canvas.

Simply including the script path in the remote page would have been too easy. So my question is, is it programmatically possible to load the JS SDK from an arbitrary domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, is it programmatically possible to load the JS SDK from an arbitrary domain ?

Of course it is – countless websites use it, outside of Facebook.

You might have to specify the domain in your app settings, though. Otherwise Facebook will not allow features like f.e. login/connecting to the app from really “arbitrary” domains.

Comment: I am kind of confused. The friend invite dialog is not part of the app per se, it just an entry point to it. In addition, Facebook won't let me specify a domain (say localhost) that isn't derived from the URLs integrated with the app.

Comment: you can download externally, yes. but the app invites are facebook canvas app specific(as they are app invites, not the domain), but you can invoke share and other requests from external domain. you can find some work around like taking publish stream permission, and posting the link to friends timeline.

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury: So you're saying there is no way to invoke the dialog from outside the canvas, thank you for clearing that up. I intend to control the app flow initiation according to whether the User has been notified about using the app, in case of which the friend invite is simply skipped.

Comment: you can invoke other dialogs like feed, but can't invoke friend invitation if its not a canvas app. i think this link will clarify things, look at the request dialogs, [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)